# Drawing a path with CAKeyFrameAnimation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, drawing, quartz-graphics, cakeyframeanimation

I want to draw a path gradually, i.e. I want the path to appear as if it is drawn by hand. I have managed to create the path I need. I have also managed to create a CAKeyFrameAnimation that uses this path. But so far I can only move an object along this path. I would like to both move an object (say a pencil) along the path, and have the path appear as if it is drawn.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a `CAShapeLayer` with your path and animate the layer's `strokeEnd` from `0.0` to `1.0`. (This is new in iOS SDK 4.2, won't work with previous versions.)

Comment: Nice.  I missed that addition in the 4.2 release notes.

Comment: @Brad: if I'am allowed to toot my own horn, I wrote an overview about what's new in 4.2: http://oleb.net/blog/2010/11/whats-new-in-ios-sdk-4-2/

Comment: Very nice. Thank you so much.